# Opening app from different android Browser

Tags: browser

Till now I have been using the default browser with my Samsung Galaxy S2. When Browsing if I found and clicked on  a link that was from Wikipedia or IMDB for instance it would ask and give the choice if I wanted to open them in the "Internet" Browser or the installed IMDB/Wikipedia App. I have since tried other Browser Apps. (Firefox, Dolphin, Skyfire, Opera etc) and none of these appear to pop up with the option to open them in an app. They go straight to the website. The only app I have found that does offer the choice is Chrome, but it seems to crash a bit too often. Am just wondering if I am missing something in the the other browsers I have looked at. I like Dolphin and Firefox, but would like to see them offer the option to open sites in installed apps. Is there options to get them to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because those browsers (Firefox, Dolphin, Skyfire, Opera) you have tested at the end of 2012 don't support or have problems with calling external intents.

[Here is](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653833) the issue about implementation that feature on Firefox.

Related information -  [how to use intent filters to open external Android app from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser).